# Does dashDB supports spatial objects?

Tags: dashdb

I need to know if DashDB supports "spatial objects" and "spatial queries" (i.e. can we store in DashDB points, or areas, or polygons and query those "objects"?). I know that for PostgreSQL, for example, this is supported by installing an add-on called PostGIS. But what about DashDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. dashDB's spatial data and indexing support comes from DB2, so it's actually very mature although dashDB is a relatively new product. See more here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/learn_how/loaddata_gsdata.html

Search the web for `dashdb` plus `geospatial` and you'll find plenty of information.

Comment: Thanks Raj! Also, the link you posted explain how to load spatial data file into dashdb, but is there an API one could use to upload spatial objects, say one by one as they are generated by a program?

Comment: Hi user7254195, you could do this with regular SQL insert statements when you pass in the spatial object by value in the SQL text. You can use WKT format with the ST_GeomFromText (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/rsbp4080.html) or WKB format with ST_GeomFromWKB.

Further functions here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/db2sb169.html

Comment: Another alternative you might consider is to go via Cloudant and put your new spatial objects there as GeoJSON documents and set up automatic replication into dashDB. https://cloudant.com/blog/warehousing-geojson-documents/#.WEe5pHcfl0s